# How to create multiple line charts from one js function

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization, jinja2

I'm trying to use [Google line charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) as part of a flask project of mine. However I don't just want one graph, I have a dictionary of lists, with each of those lists needing to be converted into a line chart. However I'm very much not experienced with js and am unsure why nothing is showing up on the page at the moment. Any help would be much appreciated

```
GraphData={
1:[['Col1','Col2'],[Row1,Row1],[Row2,Row2]],
2:[['Col1','Col2'],[Row1,Row1],[Row2,Row2],[Row3,Row3]}
3:[['Col1','Col2','Col3',[Row1,Row1,Row1],[Row2,Row2,Row2]}


#In the <head> area:

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    {% for Vars in GraphData %}
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var Data =GraphData[Vars]
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(Datas}

            var options = {
                title: 'Graph Data',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' }
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(Vars));

            chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>
    {%endfor%}


and in the <body> section:

{% for Vars in GraphData %}
<div id={{Vars}} style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way around. You don't need any `for Vars` that's a job for JavaScript. Just convert your GraphData to JSON.

Comment: Also, can you spot the error? `.arrayToDataTable(Datas}`

Comment: `var Data =GraphData[Vars]` and than suddenly you use `.arrayToDataTable(Datas}` ? why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of convert your data to JSON and if needed [parse it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).
- Create a function `processAllCharts()` that loops all your data
- Call that function as callback: `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(processAllCharts);`
- Inside that loop send every piece of data to `drawChart`
- Create dynamically your chart DIVs

```js
const GraphData = [
  [
    ['Year', 'Foo', 'Bar'],
    ['2017', 2000, 400],
    ['2018', 660, 1120],
    ['2019', 1030, 540],
  ],
  [
    ['Year', 'Lorem', 'Ipsum'],
    ['2014', 780, 1400],
    ['2015', 998, 770],
    ['2016', 660, 1120],
  ],
  [
    ['Year', 'Dolor', 'Sit Amet'],
    ['2017', 660, 1120],
    ['2018', 1030, 540],
  ],
];

const EL_gAllCharts = document.querySelector("#gAllCharts");
const chartOptions = {
  title: 'Graph Data',
  curveType: 'function',
  legend: {
    position: 'bottom'
  }
};

function drawChart(data) {
  // Create charts
  const EL_gChart = document.createElement("div");
  EL_gChart.classList.add("gChart");
  gAllCharts.append(EL_gChart);

  const gData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data)
  const chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(EL_gChart);
  chart.draw(gData, chartOptions);
}

function processAllCharts() {
  GraphData.forEach(drawChart);
}

google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(processAllCharts);
```

```css
.gChart {
  height: 260px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="gAllCharts"></div>
```